how can we decode transaction data using rust?
As we all know, we can decode transaction data when a known method is called like this.
[...]
fn main() {
    let input = "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";
    let input = hex::decode(input)?;

    // Decode the input using the generated `swapExactTokensForTokens` bindings.
    let decoded = swapExactTokensForTokensCall::abi_decode(&input, false);

[...]
}

But how can we decode the data when we don't know which method is called? We can read the function signature data from the first 4 bytes of data, which can be used to determine what function is called. But how can we use alloy-rs to decode the data further using abi?

I was able to find the solution and here it is.
use std::error::Error;
use alloy::json_abi::JsonAbi;
use alloy::primitives::Bytes;
use ethers::abi::Abi;
use log::debug;
use serde_json::from_reader;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::str;

fn load_abi(file_path: &str) -> Abi {
    // Open the ABI file
    let file = File::open(file_path).expect("ABI file not found.");
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    // Parse the ABI
    from_reader(reader).expect("Failed to parse ABI.")
}

fn decode_call(abi: &Abi, data: Bytes) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    // Extract the function selector (first 4 bytes)
    let selector = &data[..4];

    // Find the function from the ABI using the selector
    let function = abi
        .functions()
        .find(|func| func.short_signature() == selector)
        .expect("Function not found in ABI.");

    // Decode the function inputs
    let inputs = &data[4..]; // Rest of the data after the 4-byte selector
    let decoded = function.decode_input(inputs)?;

    // Print decoded arguments
    println!("Function: {}", function.name);
    for (i, token) in decoded.iter().enumerate() {
        println!("Arg {}: {:?}", i, token);
    }

    Ok(())
}

pub fn decode_uniswap_v3_call(
    input_data: Bytes,
    abi_file_path: &str,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let abi = load_abi(abi_file_path);

    println!("\n=========\n");
    // Decode the call data
    match decode_call(&abi, input_data) {
        Ok(_) => println!("Decoding successful"),
        Err(e) => eprintln!("Error decoding: {}", e),
    }

    Ok(())
}

